# My laptop gets too hot when rendering in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I am having overheating issues with my MacBook Pro retina
I have this configuration

MacBook Pro Retina 15"
Processor 2.4 GHz Intel Core i7
Memory 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
Graphics NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M 1024 MB
Software  OS X 10.9.5

Blender is an amazing tool, but working with cycles my computer
gets too hot. I have tried using last CUDA version but the problem still happens.

Any advice?

Comment: What can I say, sell this machine, don't buy overpriced icrap again..overheating is typical

Answer (score 6):

I have the same laptop, and it does indeed get hot. But this isn't really an issue specific to Cycles or even this laptop, any CPU / GPU heavy computation that has good multithreading will do it, and laptops often just aren't made to run cool under such loads.

I suggest to use CPU rendering with a lower number of threads like 2 or 3 instead of using an automatic number of threads. This mobile GPU isn't faster than the CPU in most scenes anyway. Cycles doesn't have an explicit way to specify using fewer GPU cores, though you could try decreasing the tile size to make it render slower and hopefully get it to run cooler as well then.